# Compare dates in laravel

Tags: php, date, laravel

I have this field `$data->created_at` and would like to only show data if it's `> 30 minutes` old

in my view I have:

```
@if ($data->created_at > strtotime('30 minutes'))
    show data
@endif
```

This doesn't work. I've also built this statement in the controller, but it doesn't work. It seems to be affected by Carbon in some way.

What's the best way to do this in Laravel?

Answer (score 4):

A more 'Laravel way' of doing this would be,

```
@if($data->created_at > (new \Carbon\Carbon())->subMins(30))
  show data
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel's created_at and updated_at fields are \DateTime Objects. You should be able to do this using

```
@if($data->created_at > \new DateTime('-30 minutes'))
    show data
@endif
```

Comment: Technically they are Carbon objects.

Comment: Technically Carbon objects are DateTime objects.

Comment: Also true, but it's worth knowing that they are Carbon as it provides a lot of additional functionality on top of DateTime.